# How to access strings declared inside a particular resource file in android

Tags: android, string, localization, resources

The idea is to read all the strings declared inside a strings.xml file named `strings_temp.xml` for example, that has the following in it:

```
<resources>
    <string name="string_one">String one</string>
    <string name="string_two">String two</string>
</resources>
```

and this string resource file exists in values-ru also (so we have localization).

I have searched on StackOverflow and i know we can read through all the strings in the app but i do not want to go through so much of processing just to lookup for a particular string whose id and value i may not know (it is all dynamic).

What should i do in such a case?